# Kill a running shell script, and kill all process running within it

Tags: shell-script, process, kill

I have a shell script running in the background, which runs 5 different jobs.

When I run the shell script all 5 jobs start running in order.
When I kill this shell, whichever process is running, will still continue to run, even though I have killed the shell.

```
$ bash shell.sh & echo $!
```

this gives me the PID of the shell, which allows me to kill it later if I wish to do so at some point.

```
#!/bin/bash

JOB1
JOB2
JOB3
JOB4
JOB5
```

How can I make the shell kill all process running within, once it has been killed?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a bgpids

cleanup() {
    for pid in "${bgpids[@]}"; do
        kill -9 "$pid"
    done
}
trap "cleanup" SIGINT SIGTERM

sometask &
bgpids+=("$!")
```

Comment: `jobs -p` works for pids. But `kill -- -0` should be enough.

Comment: I forgot that `kill` could effectively look up children. Good catch!

Comment: It doesnt look up children - but if everybody's in the same process group then just kill the group. `kill -0` is a whole different animal to `kill -- -0`.